# Delete a value from array if exist or if no exist push it to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array define like :

```
selectedDocumentID = [];
```

Next i have function when i get the ID, and other function where i give the id as parameter. When i click in element with id this id is going to this modifyArray. 
Next i check the id using console.log (its working and i get id).
After that i create a new array list that include a selectedDocument array. (it work). 
And i want to push to list a id if it not exist or if exist just slice it from list...

```
modifyArray(id) {
  let selectedDocumentID = [];

  let id = 10;

  console.log('this is: ' + id);
  console.log(this.selectedDocumentID);
  let list = this.selectedDocumentID;

  let index = list.findIndex( x => x === id);
  console.log(index);
  if (index !== id) {
    list.push(id);
    console.log(list);
    this.selectedDocumentID = list;
  }
  else {
    list = list.slice(list.indexOf(id));
    console.log(list);
    this.selectedDocumentID = list;
  }
}
```

So for exmaple. I click for document with id 2,4,5,6.

My selectedDocumentID = [2,4,5,6] and list also have [2,4,5,6].

Next i click to document with id 8 and my arrays = [2,4,5,6,8],
after that i click to document with id 5 and my arrays you look like [2,4,6,8].
What i am doing wrong?

[Code sample:](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpWgGM)

Comment: When you click document with id 5 you get [2,4,6,8]. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yep, this i want. But this code do not do this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try following code snippet

```
var index = list.findIndex(x => x==id)
// here you can check specific property for an object whether it exist in your array or not

if (index === -1){
    list.push(id);
}
else console.log("object already exists")
```

**Update**
The problem in your code is that you are overriding the list

```
modifyArray(id) {
  let selectedDocumentID = [];

  let id = 10;

  console.log('this is: ' + id);
  console.log(this.selectedDocumentID);
  let list = this.selectedDocumentID;

  let index = list.findIndex( x => x === id);
  console.log(index);
  if (index !== id) {
    list.push(id);
    console.log(list);
    this.selectedDocumentID = list;
  }
  else {
  list.slice(list.indexOf(id));
    console.log(list);
    this.selectedDocumentID = list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please look now at Code Sample :)
I tried this way and when i try delete only '5', i get [5,6,8]. And this dont slice 5, but 2 and 3 from array :/

Comment: you can use slice operator  list.splice(index,1)

Comment: If i write there index,1 i got empty array

Comment: splice method return the item removed from array

Comment: Also i removed list, and work only at this.selectedDocumentID for not duplicate the same value :P You help me a lot :) And replace slice for a splice. With splice its work as is should :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [xor](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#xor) lodash function to make your code simpler. For example:

```
modifyArray(id) {
  this.selectedDocumentID = _.xor(this.selectedDocumentID, [id]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this gem, it's insane what you can do if you know how data structures/statistical mathematics works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove:

```
list.splice(index, 1);
```

`slice` just extracts a portion, which I guess you can also use, but then like this:

```
list = list.slice(index, index + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by javascript also

```js
var tag_story = [];
function checkElemet()
{  
  var  id_tag = document.getElementById("ele").value,
    position = tag_story.indexOf(id_tag); 
  if ( ~position ) tag_story.splice(position, 1);
  else tag_story.push(id_tag);
  console.log(tag_story);
}
```

```html
<input id="ele" type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"/>
<input type="button" onclick="checkElemet()" value="check"/>
```